# ArrayAdapter - Making a spinner?

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

I'm following this ^ tutorial on making a "spinner" but when I get to this code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I get the "cannot be resolved to a type" error on:

```
ArrayAdapter
```

I'm not sure what to do here. I've done everything exactly how they said to, but I get these errors for some reason.

Comment: Ctrl-shift-O  cannot be stressed enough...This should be a muscle memory reaction to seeing red underlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you not missing an import?

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
```

If you are developing in Eclipse, try a shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O, which organizes your imports

Comment: Yes! I always forget that! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are working with eclipse: Press `Ctrl+Shift+O` ("Organize imports"). That seaches for everything you need to import in the current open file and adds the `import` statements. It also cleans unneeded imports. Way easier than managing them by hand. :)